# Using Webpack to compile sass (only) and convert referenced images to base64

Tags: webpack, sass, base64

I am using Webpack to compile my scss file to css. webpack.config file below. Notice that I'm using my main sass file as the entry point. Truth be told, I'm not entirely sure how these loaders are working, but, at present, they do:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: ['./scss/main.scss'],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build/css',
        filename: '[name].css'
    },
    mode : 'production',
    watch: true,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].css',
                            outputPath: '../css/'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'extract-loader',
                        options: {
                            publicPath: ''
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

}

I am trying to also incorporate a system of converting my background images, referenced in the main.scss stylesheet, into base64 strings. I believe this should be possible with the file loader, or url loader, but I can't get either to work. Also tried [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-inline-loader) to no avail. Can anyone suggest how I could acheive this please?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have achieved this using plugins to the postcss-loader, namely [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-base64), like so:

`const base64 = require('postcss-base64');`

```
{
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
        plugins: () => [
            require('autoprefixer'),
            require('postcss-minimize'),
            base64({
                extensions: ['.jpg', '.png']
            })
            // require('postcss-font-base64')
        ]
    }
},
```

Works perfectly.